# I want to extract the week based on sysdate in Oracle SQL, what function do i use

Tags: sql, oracle, function

select datepart(year, '2017/08/25') as week;

I believe this is for mysql but does not work for oracle sql

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  In no database does `datepart(year, '2017/08/25')` return a value that I would ever call `week`.

Comment: Oracle has W, WW and IW [format elements](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/Format-Models.html#GUID-EAB212CF-C525-4ED8-9D3F-C76D08EEBC7A) that you can use with `to_char()`. If none of those do what you want then you will have to explain what exactly you are trying to do.

Comment: You want the week of the year the date falls on, 1-52?

Answer (score 1):

Week of year (1-53) where week 1 starts on the first day of the year and continues to the seventh day of the year.

```
select to_char(trunc(sysdate),'WW') from dual;
```

Week of year (1-52 or 1-53) based on the ISO standard.

```
select to_char(trunc(sysdate),'IW') from dual;
```

Taken from [Oracle docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/sql_elements004.htm#SQLRF00210)

Comment: TRUNC for me it's a metter of habit when I'm dealing with dates ;-)